# Проблема с RadioButton и Command, изменяющие свойтво

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Проблема моего кода заключается в том, что Binding RadioButton'а не дает делегату команды изменить свойство. Делегат его меняет, а Binding, его меняет на старое значение. Мне нужно что бы изменить значение свойства можно было по клику на RadioButton или кнопку клавиатуры.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <con:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="ETBConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:TestViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}"/>
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ETBConverter}, ConverterParameter=State1}" Content="State1"/>
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ETBConverter}, ConverterParameter=State2}" Content="State2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    State1,
    State2,
}
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private TestEnum _someProperty;
    public TestEnum SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_someProperty != value)
            {
                _someProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public Command SomeCommand { get; private set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        _someProperty = TestEnum.State2;
        SomeCommand = new Command(SomeCommand_Execute);
    }

    private void SomeCommand_Execute(object obj)
    {
        SomeProperty = SomeProperty == TestEnum.State1 ? TestEnum.State2 : TestEnum.State1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Кстати, у меня ваш пример прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш пример у меня прекрасно работает, возможно, вы ошиблись с конвертером.

Но в любом случае передачу данных в VM по идее лучше имплементировать при помощи команды. Это реализуется, например, так.

Во-первых, вспомогательная типизация значений в XAML. Мы ведь не хотим, чтобы параметр конвертера был строкой?

```
public class TestEnumExtension : TypedValueExtension<TestEnum>
{
    public TestEnumExtension(TestEnum value) : base(value) { }
}

public class TypedValueExtension<T> : MarkupExtension
{
    public TypedValueExtension(T value) { Value = value; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp) { return Value; }
}
```

Имея это, немного переделаем исходник:

```
<RadioButton
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Mode=OneWay,
                        Converter={StaticResource ETBConverter},
                        ConverterParameter={local:TestEnum State1}}"
    Content="State1"
    Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{local:TestEnum State1}"/>
<RadioButton
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Mode=OneWay,
                        Converter={StaticResource ETBConverter},
                        ConverterParameter={local:TestEnum State2}}"
    Content="State2"
    Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{local:TestEnum State2}"/>
```

Плюс обновление в code-behind, чтобы работало не со строками, а с правильным значением:

```
void SomeCommand_Execute(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null) // set new value
        SomeProperty = (TestEnum)obj;
    else             // flip existing value
        SomeProperty = (SomeProperty == TestEnum.State1) ? TestEnum.State2 : TestEnum.State1;
}
```

Реализация конвертера теперь тривиальна:

```
public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (TestEnum)value == (TestEnum)parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // обратное преобразование больше не нужно
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Всё!

Comment: Твой код у меня работает. Надо будет приучить себя писать расширения разметки. Конвертер я брал где-то на английском stackoverflow еще хрен знает когда.

Comment: А можно еще чуть дописать ConvertBack и можно уйти от команды в RadioButton :-)

Comment: @Nodon: Можно, так работает тоже. Можно по-всякому. :) Но мне кажется идеологически правильнее через команду.

Comment: @Nodon: Не все конвертеры одинаково полезны :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо отказаться от обычной привязки кнопок и везде использовать **Command**. В вашем случае именно **Command** дает возможность использовать один обработчик для разных контролов, так что грех этим не воспользоваться.

Пример XAML:

```
 <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Play" Executed="Play_OnExecuted"></CommandBinding>
 </Window.CommandBindings>

<Menu>
    <MenuItem Name="First"  Command="Play"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Name="Second" Command="Play"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Если вы используете свою команду, а не ту которую предоставляет фреймворк - соответственно добавьте класс с ней в проект.

Comment: Не совсем пойму как ты себе это представляешь.

Comment: @Nodon, отредактировал ответ

Comment: @Nodon: Для RadioButton вместо Binding используй тоже команду.

Comment: @VlaD Да, но мне же так и так придется биндить свойство IsChecked, только теперь уже в одностроннем режиме. Так ведь?

Comment: @Nodon: Хм. Получается, что да.

Comment: @VladD Сделал так, не помогает все равно(

Comment: Как именно не помогает?